# Implement Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff expansion

Tags: series-expansion, physics

I wish to calculate the recursive formula,

$$\mathrm{e}^{-A_1 \Delta t/2}\mathrm{e}^{-A_0 \Delta t/2}B\mathrm{e}^{A_0 \Delta t/2}\mathrm{e}^{A_1 \Delta t/2} $$

with the BCH expansion to second order of $A$,

$$\mathrm{e}^{-A}B\mathrm{e}^{A} = B - [A, B] + \frac{1}{2}[A,[A,B]] + \mathcal{O}(A^3)$$

I tried the following code,

```
ClearAll[ExpandNCM]
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Plus, c___]] := 
Distribute[h[a, b, c], Plus, h, Plus, ExpandNCM[h[##]] &]
ExpandNCM[(h : NonCommutativeMultiply)[a___, b_Times, c___]] := 
Most[b] ExpandNCM[h[a, Last[b], c]]
ExpandNCM[a_] := ExpandAll[a]

ClearAll[ CommutatorBrack]
CommutatorBrack[a_, b_] := a ** b - b ** a

ClearAll[ ExpandBCH]
ExpandBCH[a_, b_] := 
ExpandNCM[b] -  ExpandNCM[ CommutatorBrack[a, b]]  + 
ExpandNCM[CommutatorBrack[a, CommutatorBrack[a, b]]]

ExpandBCH[a, b] // ExpandNCM
```

gave me,

```
 b - a ** b + a ** (a ** b - b ** a) + b ** a - (a ** b - b ** a) ** a
```

I used some of the @evanb's code

```
commutator[A_][B_] := A ** B - B ** A
```

```
BCH[n_][dt_, A_, B_] := ExpandAll[NestList[commutator[A], B, n].(Table[dt^i, {i, 0, n}]/Map[Factorial, Range[0, n]])] + O[dt]^(n + 1)
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, Times[\[CapitalDelta]t, M__], 
T___] := \[CapitalDelta]t NonCommutativeMultiply[H, Times[M], T]
NonCommutativeMultiply[H__, Plus[A_, B__], T___] := 
H ** A ** T + H ** Plus[B] ** T
```

This gives me right answer in the first place

```
ExpandAll[BCH[2][\[CapitalDelta]t, A0, P0]]
```

But when I try to calculate

```
ExpandAll[
BCH[2][\[CapitalDelta]t, A1, 
ExpandAll[BCH[2][\[CapitalDelta]t, A0, B]]]]
```

Comment: Some useful information may be found on,  http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~mehen/760/ProblemSets/BCH.pdf

Comment: I'm not in the field, but you've got a finite formula, ignoring the big-O. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I added some details, thank you very much for your time and consideration

Comment: What is the question here?  If your question is if there is a built-in implementation of this in Mathematica, then the answer is no.

Comment: @QuantumDot I'm sorry for not being clear, I wish to calculate $$\mathrm{e}^{-A_1 \Delta t/2}\mathrm{e}^{-A_0 \Delta t/2}B\mathrm{e}^{A_0 \Delta t/2}\mathrm{e}^{A_1 \Delta t/2} $$ to the second order with $$\mathrm{e}^{-A}B\mathrm{e}^{A} = B - [A, B] + \frac{1}{2}[A,[A,B]] + \mathcal{O}(A^3)$$

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the BCH pretty easily using an operator form of commutator

```
NumericQ[\[CapitalDelta]t] = True;

Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, Times[a_?NumericQ, M__], T___] := a H**Times[M]**T
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, Plus[A_, B__], T___] :=  H ** A ** T + H ** Plus[B] ** T

commutator[A_][B_] := A ** B - B ** A

BCH[n_][A_, B_] :=  ExpandAll[
    NestList[commutator[A], B, n].(1/Map[Factorial, Range[0, n]])] + order[A, n + 1]
```

We should give some details about how `order` is supposed to work:

```
order[\[CapitalDelta]t^pow_. A_, n_] := order[\[CapitalDelta]t, n pow]
order /: Times[coefficient_., a_^power_., order[a_, n_]] := order[a, n + power]
order /: a_?NumericQ order[parameter_, power_] := order[parameter, power] /; FreeQ[a, parameter]
order /: Plus[Times[a_^high_, factors___], order[a_, low_]] := order[a, low] /; low <= high
order /: Plus[order[a_, low_], order[a_, high_]] :=  order[a, low] /; low <= high

(* And if it shows up in ** the whole operator should be tossed. *)
NonCommutativeMultiply[H___, counting_order, T___] := counting
```

Then when I do `Collect[BCH[2][\[CapitalDelta]t F, BCH[2][\[CapitalDelta]t A, B]], \[CapitalDelta]t]`

I get

```
B + \[CapitalDelta]t (A ** B - B ** A - B ** F + 
F ** B) + \[CapitalDelta]t^2 (A ** A ** B/2 - A ** B ** A - 
A ** B ** F + B ** A ** A/2 + B ** A ** F + B ** F ** F/2 + 
F ** A ** B - F ** B ** A - F ** B ** F + F ** F ** B/2) + 
order[\[CapitalDelta]t, 3]
```

which without explicit checking, I hope is the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem here is that the `NonCommutativeMultiply` would not be expanded by `Expand` or `Simplify`. So when I can not write the results as $c_1 + c_2 \Delta t + c_3 \Delta t^2 + \mathcal{O}(\Delta t^3)$. The function `ExpandNCM ` in my code works some time, but it fails to fully expand the result.

Comment: i updated with some utilities that allow a special treatment of ∆t.

Comment: Thank you, I added some information in my question.

Comment: I updated my code to allow for repeated expansion.

Comment: I compute `comutator[1][B]`, but it gives $1**B-B**1$, how to do a more redefinition to get 0 of this computation.

Comment: I think you can just define `commutator[1][B_] = 0`.